# Perguntas e respostas utilizando Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estou fazendo um `<form>` que retorna uma interação caso a resposta esteja errada.

A ideia é: caso o usuário selecione a resposta certa, o `<button>` altere a cor para verde e/ou vermelho para errado.
Isto utilizando `$.ajax` dinamicamente sem que a página seja atualizada!

Alguém teria ideia de como pegar o **valor** selecionado no *radio button* e comparar com a resposta correta, dentro desse código? Ou teria uma outra forma melhor?

```
<form name="frm.$row[question_id]." role="form" id="submitForm.$row[question_id].">
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="question_id" placeholder="Name" value=".$row[question_id]." required="" />
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="user_id" placeholder="User" value=".$myid." required="" />
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input.$row[question_id]." type="radio" name="resposta" id="blankRadio1" value="A" aria-label="..." onClick="mostrar.$row[question_id].()" />
        A) .$row[option1].
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input.$row[question_id]." type="radio" name="resposta" id="blankRadio1" value="B" aria-label="..." onClick="mostrar.$row[question_id].()" />
        B) .$row[option2].
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input.$row[question_id]." type="radio" name="resposta" id="blankRadio1" value="C" aria-label="..." onClick="mostrar.$row[question_id].()" />
        C) .$row[option3].
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input.$row[question_id]." type="radio" name="resposta" id="blankRadio1" value="D" aria-label="..." onClick="mostrar.$row[question_id].()" />
        D) .$row[option4].
    </div>
    <br />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn btn-block" id="submitbtn.$row[question_id]." name="botao.$row[question_id]." disabled>Responder</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#submitForm.$row[question_id].").on("submit", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#submitbtn").text("Please wait..");
            var userForm = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: "insertData.php",
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                data: userForm,
                success: function (response) {
                    $("#submitbtn.$row[question_id].").attr("disabled", true);
                    $("#success").show();
                    $("#success").html("Data inserted successfully");
                    $("#submitbtn.$row[question_id].").text("Gabarito: .$row[answer].");
                    $("#submitForm")[0].reset();
                },
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Antes de mais nada..

faltou informações na sua pergunta, portanto sugiro que **NÃO DEIXE** de ver [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) e [Como fazer uma boa pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para assim, elaborar uma pergunta sem deixar qualquer detalhe para trás.. Neste caso, faltou o seu código [php](/questions/tagged/php) para complementar, mas sem problemas!

---

### Montei um *"esqueminha"* de questões para perguntas/respostas bem simples utilizando jQuery

```js
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: `questoes.php?obter-questoes`,
        type: "get",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: (json, status, xhr) => {
        console.log(json);
            $("#frmMain h3").html(Object.keys(json)[0]);
            Object.values(json)[0].forEach((value, index) => {
                $("#frmMain ul").append(`<li><input type="radio" name="respostas" value="${index}" />${value}</li>`);
            });
        }
    });
});

$("#frmMain").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: `questoes.php?obter-respostas`,
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        data: {
            "questao": $("#frmMain h3").html(),
            "resposta": $("[type=radio][name=respostas]:checked").val()
        },
        success: (json, status, xhr) => {
            Object.entries(json).forEach((value, index) => {
                if ((value[1] == true)) {
                    $("[type=radio][name=respostas]").each(function() {
                        if ((value[0] == $(this).parent().text())) {
                            $(this).parent().css("background-color", "lime");
                        } else {
                            $(this).parent().css("background-color", "red");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    })

});
```

```css
form { max-width: 30%; }
li { list-style-type: none; }
ul { padding-inline-start: 0px !important; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Perguntas e Respostas</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="frmMain">
        <h3></h3>
        <ul></ul>
        <button type="submit">Responder</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### Já no back-end é um código bem pequeno..

Contudo daria para fazer utilizando apenas o JavaScript

- **questoes.php**

```php
<?php  
    
    // Com apenas 4 questões, mas poderá utilizar alguma API para obter questões (tipo: Quiz)
    $questoes = array(
        "Quem é o atual presidente do Brasil?" => array(
            "Lula" => false,
            "Dilma Rousseff" => false,
            "Jair Bolsonaro" => true,
            "Michel Temer" => false
        ),
        "Quanto é 2 x 2 = ?" => array(
            "2" => false,
            "5" => false,
            "8" => false,
            "4" => true
        ),
        "O que significa Legend em Português?" => array(
            "Legenda" => true,
            "História" => false,
            "Conto" => false,
            "Legado" => false
        ),
        "Qual melhor site de perguntas e respostas?" => array(
            "Reddit" => false,
            "Stack Overflow em Português" => true,
            "Quora" => false,
            "Comunidades da Microsoft" => false
        )
    );


    if (isset($_GET["obter-questoes"])) {
        // randomiza os indices das chaves saindo de forma "aleatória"..
        $questao = array_keys($questoes)[rand(0, count($questoes) - 1)];

        // adiciona a um novo array contendo apenas as chaves pais/filhos sem a resposta true/false
        $retorno[$questao] = array_keys($questoes[$questao]);

        // imprime o resultado (será o response da solicitação ajax)
        print_r(json_encode($retorno));

    } else if (isset($_GET["obter-respostas"])) {
        
        // uma simples busca baseado no nome da questão e a resposta selecionada..
        print_r(json_encode($questoes[$_POST["questao"]]));
    }   

?>
```

---

[Teste o código!](http://sopt.gleisin-dev.ml/518825/)

Comment: Vlw, gleisin-dev. Obrigado!

Consegui logo dps, comparando a variável userFrom com o valor selecionado no radio. Não tava dando certo pois e mais de um valor que essa variável pega. Arrumei isso e deu certo.

if(userForm == "resposta='.$row['answer'].'&question_id='.$row['question_id'].'&user_id='.$myid.'") { $("#submitbtn'.$row['question_id'].'").removeClass("btn-danger").addClass("btn-success");
}
else{$("#submitbtn'.$row['question_id'].'").removeClass("btn-success").addClass("btn-danger");}